# Функция подсчета гласных и согласных англ. алфавита

Tags: c

```
void input_and_counting_vowels(unsigned short max)
{
    unsigned short ctr = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    unsigned short count_vowels = 0, count_consonants = 0;
    char ch = 0;

    unsigned char vowels[5+1];
    unsigned char consonants[max+1];

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < max; ctr++) {
        printf("\tВведите %2hu символ из %2hu: ", ctr+1, max);

        if((ch = getchar()) == EOF) {
            fputs("\nПроизошел сбой при вводе символа!\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
        {
            vowels[x] = ch;
            x++;
            count_vowels++;
        } else if(ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U')
        {
            vowels[x] = ch;
            x++;
            count_vowels++;
        }
        else
        {
            consonants[y] = ch;
            y++;
        }

        clear_stdin();
    }

    vowels[x] = '\0';
    consonants[y] = '\0';

    count_consonants = max - count_vowels;

    printf("\nВы ввели %hu символов.\n", max);
    printf("\tГласных: %s (%hu).\n", vowels, count_vowels);
    printf("\tСогласных: %s (%hu).\n", consonants, count_consonants);
}
```

max - введенное юзером кол-во символов. Моя функция clear_stdin() вместо fflush(stdin), т.к. fflush() почему-то не работает.

Массивы vowels[], consonants[] хранят все введенным пользователем гласные и согласные соответственно. +1 для символа конца строки, чтобы вывести массив как строку.

Вопросы:

1. можно ли как-то эффективнее распределить память для массивов (vowels[], consonants[])?
2. существует ли другой способ подсчета гласных и согласных?
3. почему Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express ругается на max (требуется константное выражение)? Тогда как gcc в Cygwin компилирует без проблем.
4. можно ли в общем как-то улучшить данную функцию?

Я пока что изучаю Си (это мой первый язык программирования), так что приветствуются советы, рекомендации и конструктивная критика.

Comment: @dr_kraken, первая ошибка -- это `char ch` сравнивается с EOF в `if`.

В кодировке cp1251 (русские в винде) это буковка 'я'.

А что произойдет, если введено больше 5 гласных? 

(*Массив vowels[] переполнится и потрете что-то в памяти.*)

--

Наверное, если Вы хотите *хранить*, а потом раздельно печатать введенные гласные и проч., то нужны или 2 массива размером `max + 1`, или один размером `max + 2`, который заполняется с двух концов (навстречу друг-другу), а потом один из концов реверсируется.

Лишние +2 -- это для завешающих символьные строки ноликов (если  самому печатать в цикле лень).

Comment: Вообще, именно для подсчета, достаточно 2-х переменных -- `n_vowels` и `total`.

--

У M$ очевидно в какком-то из инклюдников `max` уже как-то оперделена (скорее всего это макрос или функция).

--

Далее предполагается, что речь об однобайтных символах.


Если хотите хранить информацию какие именно символы  были введены хотя бы один раз -- достаточно 256 бит (строка 16 байт).

Если нужно знать, сколько раз был введен каждый символ (порядок неважен), то достаточно массива из 256 счетчиков.

Естественно, перед употреблением и то и другое надо проинициализировать.

Comment: @avp а разве getchar() при достижения конца файла или ошибки не возвращает EOF, которое определено как -1?

vowels[max+1] исправлено. А как-то по другому не получится задать размер массивов vowels[] и consonants[]? Допустим, юзер ввел 10 символов, из них 4 гласные, и 6 согласных (vowels[3+1] и consonants[5+1]). Ведь заранее неизвестно сколько будет и тех и других букв, следовательно размер массивов только max+1.

А что насчет вопросов 2 и 3?

Comment: @dr_kraken: Да. Но это `-1` типа `int`, а если вы его присваиваете `char`'у, оно преобразуется в 255, которое соответствует русскому `'я'` в одной из кодировок.

Функция `getchar()` возвращает `int` не просто так.

Comment: >разве getchar() при достижения конца файла или ошибки не возвращает EOF, которое определено как -1

Это стандартная ошибка: `getchar()` возвращает `int`, а у вас переменная типа `char`. Никогда не используйте `char` там, где предполагается `int`. В данном примере `int(-1)` - это никак не `char(-1)`, оно же 255, оно же 0xFF.

Comment: @VladD Значит надо сравнивать ch != -1? Или как?

    char ch = -1;
    
    if(ch == EOF)
        puts("Yes, ch == EOF!");
    else puts("No, ch != EOF!");

Почему тогда выполняется 1 оператор?

Comment: @dr_kraken: да нет же! НЕЛЬЗЯ объявлять `ch` как `char`, иначе вы **не сможете** отличить выходное значение `getchar()` -1 от 255.

Comment: @dr_kraken, про EOF и int @VladD Вам уже написал.

Если сосем конкретно, то напишите

     int ch; // именно int, а не char !!!

Про 2) и 3).  Эээеее... Вроде бы уже написал в комментариях. 

Еще раз 2) -- зависит от того, что именно Вы называете подсчетом.

а 3) -- ругается, поскольку имя переменной пересекается с  уже определенным в файлах Microfoft символом (переменной, константой именем функции и т.п.)

--

Про эффективный  расход памяти и ввод произвольного (суммарно до MAX) количества -- тоже написал -- заполняете один массив с двух концов (i -- увеличиваете, j -- уменьшаете).

Comment: @avp Вы предлагаете, заменить массивы vowels[] и consonants[] на один, и вести подсчет гласных и согласных в нем? А как тогда выводить из него гласные и согласные, как у меня, в разных строках?

Comment: @dr_kraken, думаю что-то в таком духе:


      char str[max + 2];
      int  ch, total = 0, i = 0, j = max - 1;
      str[j] = 0;
      
      while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && total < max ) {
        total++;
        if (is_vowel(ch))
          str[i++] = ch;
        else
          str[--j] = ch;
      }
      str[i] = 0;
      str_reverse(str + j, max - j - 1);
      printf ("vowels: %s\nother: %s\n", str, str + j);


не проверял...

(комментарии закончились. Лимит-с).

Answer (score 2):

Ужос-ужос-ужос. Достаточно взглянуть на первую строчку кода (с именем функции), чтобы понять, в чем Ваша основная проблема. Нельзя возлагать на функцию две разные задачи - ввод символов и их подсчет. А подсчет в Вашем случае тоже делится на две задачи: заполнение массивов и собственно подсчет. Все это надо разделить на отдельные функции.

Вот как бы я сделал экстракцию символов, если я вообще правильно понял задание. Обратите внимание, что функция extract_symbols не знает о том, как были введены строки, и не беспокоится о том, действительно ли это строки, хватит ли их и т.д. Это называется принцип единственной обязанности. Функция должна быть ответственна только за свою работу.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* extract_symbols(const char* const list, char* in, char* const out)
{
    char* cur = out;
    *cur = '\0';
    while( *in ) {
        if( strchr(list, *in) ) {
            *cur = *in;
            ++cur;
            *cur = '\0';
        }
        ++in;
    }
    return out;
}

#define BUF_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    char input[BUF_SIZE];
    char output[BUF_SIZE];

    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        puts(extract_symbols("aeiou", input, output));
        puts(extract_symbols(".,;!?", input, output));
    } while( output[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем `*cur = '\0'` на каждой итерации? Где на входе размер `out`?  

Вах-вах :)

Comment: @VadimTukaev Спасибо. Этот код для меня немного сложноват, буду разбираться. PS. Ваша прога не выводит согласных, и не подсчитывает количество тех и других. А так мне понравилось, компактно и элегантно. Было бы идеально, если бы добавили комментарии/пояснения.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, вообще-то изначально ТС делил символы на гласные *и все остальные*, а также подсчитывал (и печатал) *количество* тех и других.

Придется Вам немного модифицировать `extract_symbols()`.

Интересно, сколько же раз (считая исходный проход по символам файла до `'\n'`) придется обратиться к каждому символу в рамках требования, что программа должна быть разбита на функции, каждая из которых выполняет строго одну задачу.

--

Ну, а такой цикл ввода вообще неправильно работает

(по крайней мере не обрабатываете EOF).

Comment: @VadimTukaev Объясните вот это: const char* const list - принимает указатель на char, который нельзя изменить (const); Зачем 2-ой const перед list?. char* in - указатель типа char. А char* const out мне вообще не понятен. Если сделать так: const char* out, то компилятор ругается на char* cur = out; (зачем это? указатель на указатель?)
А вот это puts(extract_symbols(".,;!?", input, output)); для чего? Ведь если я ввожу только буквы, то этот оператор ничего не выведет. И вы не учитываете верхний и нижний регистры.

Comment: `cur` - это не указатель на указатель! Это указатель, ссылающийся на ту же память, что и `out`. А нужен он для того, чтобы иметь возможность вернуть `out` из функции (без дополнительного указателя мы бы в цикле увеличивали `out`, и после окончания цикла он бы перестал ссылаться на начало строки, которое мы и хотим вернуть).

А что касается `const * const` - один запрещает модифицировать данные, на которые ссылается указатель. Другой - запрещает модифицировать сам указатель. Вы точно читаете учебники? На всякий случай гляньте ещё тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/59558/

Comment: @dr_kraken, надо понимать, что это решение  *вовсе не Вашей* задачи.

Просто демонстрация некоторых возможностей языка (**keyword**  ***const***), позволяющих компилятору выявлять некоторые ошибки (несоответствие реализации и спецификации), но реально слабо влияющих на эффективность практического программирования.

--

Кстати, IMHO вот так

     char *cur = out;
     for (; *in; in++)
       if (strchr(list, *in)) // strchr() ищет символ в строке (см. man)
         *cur++ = *in;
     *cur = 0;
     return out;

значительно компактней (и на мой взгляд, понятней).

Comment: > Зачем *cur = '\0' на каждой итерации?

Согласен, ступил. avp исправил мой код практически до идеала.

> Где на входе размер out?

Не нужен. Буфер создается вне этой функции, там и должен контролироваться его размер. Собственно, в моем main так и сделано.

> Ну, а такой цикл ввода вообще неправильно работает (по крайней мере не обрабатываете EOF).

Не нужен. Во всяком случае, внутри ЭТОГО цикла. Это мы будем отслеживать (через feof) во внешнем цикле, который строки читает.

> И вы не учитываете верхний и нижний регистры.

    extract_symbols("aeiouAEIOU", input, output);